# How to theme the Order Details page?

Tags: 7, theming, ubercart

I know that you can change the layout of the order history/order listings pages by editing the uc_orders_user View, but how can you theme the order details page (for example, http://mysite.com/user/1/orders/5)?

I am setting my Ubercart to be used exclusively for Requests For Pricing, and I want to remove all mentions of the words "Cart", "Order", etc, and replace them with RFP-related terminology. I have been able to accomplish a lot of this via String Overrides, but the thorn in my side is the big H1 "Order (#)" tag at the top of the Order Details page. I'm hoping someone here can tell me how to theme that page so I can rename that item (and make a few other small tweaks to the page).

Thanks!